# Convert MultiIndex Columns to Standard Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

How can we convert a Pandas DataFrame containing a MultiIndex column, such as

```
                FB                  AAPL
                open    volume      open    volume
date
2019-10-30      189.56  28734995    244.76  31130522
2019-10-31      196.70  42286529    247.24  34790520
2019-11-01      192.85  21711829    249.54  37781334
```

to one with regular columns, where one of the index level is now a column in all rows

```
                open    volume      ticker  
date
2019-10-30      189.56  28734995    FB      
2019-10-31      196.70  42286529    FB      
2019-11-01      192.85  21711829    FB      
2019-10-30      244.76  31130522    AAPL
2019-10-31      247.24  34790520    AAPL
2019-11-01      249.54  37781334    AAPL
```

Answer (score 5):

Main idea is use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert MultiIndex second level to column:

```
df = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('date','ticker')).reset_index(level=1)
print (df)
           ticker    open    volume
date                               
2019-10-30   AAPL  244.76  31130522
2019-10-30     FB  189.56  28734995
2019-10-31   AAPL  247.24  34790520
2019-10-31     FB  196.70  42286529
2019-11-01   AAPL  249.54  37781334
2019-11-01     FB  192.85  21711829
```

If ordering is important then is used `ordered catagorical`s for tickers, sorting and for column to last position reassign with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df1 = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('date','ticker')).reset_index(level=1)
df1['ticker'] = pd.Categorical(df1.pop('ticker'), 
                               ordered=True, 
                               categories=df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique())
df1 = df1.sort_values(['ticker','date'])
print (df1)
              open    volume ticker
date                               
2019-10-30  189.56  28734995     FB
2019-10-31  196.70  42286529     FB
2019-11-01  192.85  21711829     FB
2019-10-30  244.76  31130522   AAPL
2019-10-31  247.24  34790520   AAPL
2019-11-01  249.54  37781334   AAPL
```